# Retrieval of the value from div using getElementsByTagName

Tags: javascript, html

Below is the sample code snippet. What I am trying to do is to get the value deal inside the `div` tag using `getElementsByTagName`.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function test() {
         var a = document.getElementsByTagName("body");
    }
    </script>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div>deal</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry but you say 'this is what I want to do' but how exactly do you want to use that? Getting it is as simple as `document.querySelector('div').textContent`. Also, use `document.body` instead of `getElementByTagName("body")`.

Comment: Why not use getElementById("id") and give an ID to your DIV?

Comment: that is the restriction i cant use id. and i used 
alert(document.querySelector('div').textContent);

it does nothing. corret me if i did something wrong.

Comment: I can;t correct you, since its not wrong and should work (check out my snippet below - it has an alert and it alerts the text). This only works properly if its the first div in your document, however, otherwise you will have to be more specific using the `querySelector`

Comment: Concerning `querySelector()`: depending on your browser you might have to add a doctype and a different meta tag to get it to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Heres a simple implementation to get your text - I use `querySelector` because it is more versatile, but that's an opinion.

```js
document.querySelector('p').textContent = document.querySelector('div').textContent;
```

```html
<div>deal</div> === <p id="output"></p>
```

Comment: using getElementsByTagName was part of the question :p

Comment: @AndreaBogazzi So? Rigidly picking a certain solution when there are more convenient ones available is a fools game.

Comment: @AndreBogazzi Just to clarify, if I ask you to pick all the apples in the orchard with a long stick, but theres a ladder right there, then why would you use the stick? :)

Comment: It was just a joke. it is fool the question itself.

Comment: @AndreBogazzi I know it was a joke :) I +1 your answer as it does the trick as well, though I have to say that going for a for loop is quite a stretch further :)

Comment: i ran the code snippet provided in the answer and it shows nothing.means no alert box with value deal.

Comment: @GauravSrivastava Okay, somebody warned me about this, the SO snippet is sandboxed so Chrome blocks `alert` calls. Let me change that to something else.

Comment: hi ,

thanks for the quick replies.

i ran the code in mozilla,chrome,IE and it is not working.

Comment: @guaravsrivasta it runs even on my android, so i cant help you any further. This code works.

Comment: may be i am doing something terribly wrong below is my jsp page code snippet.

<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML= document.querySelector('div').textContent;
</script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>deal</div> === <p id="output"></p>

</body>
</html>

Comment: You need to put your script _before your body closes_, otherwise your script cant find the elements since they have not been read yet.

Answer (score 1):

It would be more helpful if you added an ID to the div so you can access it directly, but doing it your way, this code snippet should get it:

```
var a = document.body.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].innerHTML;
```

Of course, this assumes that the markup looks you pasted everytime

Comment: I think `textContent` would probably be more correct here, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("DIV");
var value;
```

now elements is a nodelist.

```
for (var i=0; i < elements.length; i++) {
   value = elements[i].innerHTML;
}
```

if you have multiple div, you have to identify wich one is the one you care about.